# How to remove plane surface in arcore after the model is loaded in anchor?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I m trying to remove plane surface after object is loaded in Arcore. I don't know how to remove the plane surface.

My existing code is written below.I would appreciate if some one can help with that. there must be some function to call from PlaneRender.java but i dont see that could remove the plane surface after the model is loaded.

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

   /* if (isObjReplaced) {
        isObjReplaced = false;
        try {
            virtualObject.createOnGlThread(this, objName, textureName);
            virtualObject.setMaterialProperties(0.0f, 2.0f, 0.5f, 6.0f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }*/

    // Clear screen to notify driver it should not load any pixels from previous frame.
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    if (session == null) {
        return;
    }
    // Notify ARCore session that the view size changed so that the perspective matrix and
    // the video background can be properly adjusted.
    displayRotationHelper.updateSessionIfNeeded(session);

    try {
        session.setCameraTextureName(backgroundRenderer.getTextureId());

        // Obtain the current frame from ARSession. When the configuration is set to
        // UpdateMode.BLOCKING (it is by default), this will throttle the rendering to the
        // camera framerate.
        Frame frame = session.update();
        Camera camera = frame.getCamera();

        // Handle taps. Handling only one tap per frame, as taps are usually low frequency
        // compared to frame rate.

        MotionEvent tap = queuedSingleTaps.poll();
        if (tap != null && camera.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {
            for (HitResult hit : frame.hitTest(tap)) {
                // Check if any plane was hit, and if it was hit inside the plane polygon
                Trackable trackable = hit.getTrackable();
                // Creates an anchor if a plane or an oriented point was hit.
                if ((trackable instanceof Plane && ((Plane) trackable).isPoseInPolygon(hit.getHitPose()))
                        || (trackable instanceof Point
                        && ((Point) trackable).getOrientationMode()
                        == OrientationMode.ESTIMATED_SURFACE_NORMAL)) {
                    // Hits are sorted by depth. Consider only closest hit on a plane or oriented point.
                    // Cap the number of objects created. This avoids overloading both the
                    // rendering system and ARCore.
                    if (anchors.size() >= 1) {
                        anchors.get(0).detach();
                        anchors.remove(0);
                    }
                    // Adding an Anchor tells ARCore that it should track this position in
                    // space. This anchor is created on the Plane to place the 3D model
                    // in the correct position relative both to the world and to the plane.
                    anchors.add(hit.createAnchor());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Draw background.
        backgroundRenderer.draw(frame);

        // If not tracking, don't draw 3d objects.
        if (camera.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.PAUSED) {
            return;
        }

        // Get projection matrix.
        float[] projmtx = new float[16];
        camera.getProjectionMatrix(projmtx, 0, 0.1f, 100.0f);

        // Get camera matrix and draw.
        float[] viewmtx = new float[16];
        camera.getViewMatrix(viewmtx, 0);

        // Compute lighting from average intensity of the image.
        final float lightIntensity = frame.getLightEstimate().getPixelIntensity();

        // Visualize tracked points.
        PointCloud pointCloud = frame.acquirePointCloud();
        this.pointCloud.update(pointCloud);
        this.pointCloud.draw(viewmtx, projmtx);

        // Application is responsible for releasing the point cloud resources after
        // using it.
        pointCloud.release();

        // Check if we detected at least one plane. If so, hide the loading message.
        if (messageSnackbar != null) {
            for (Plane plane : session.getAllTrackables(Plane.class)) {
                if (plane.getType() == Plane.Type.HORIZONTAL_UPWARD_FACING
                        && plane.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {
                    hideLoadingMessage();

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Visualize planes.
        planeRenderer.drawPlanes(
                session.getAllTrackables(Plane.class), camera.getDisplayOrientedPose(), projmtx);

        // Visualize anchors created by touch.
        float scaleFactor = 1.0f;
        for (Anchor anchor : anchors) {
            if (anchor.getTrackingState() != TrackingState.TRACKING) {
                continue;
            }
            else{

                anchor.getPose().toMatrix(anchorMatrix, 0);

                // Update and draw the model and its shadow.
                virtualObject.updateModelMatrix(anchorMatrix, GlobalClass.scaleFactor);
                virtualObject.draw(viewmtx, projmtx, lightIntensity);


            }
            // Get the current pose of an Anchor in world space. The Anchor pose is updated
            // during calls to session.update() as ARCore refines its estimate of the world.


        }

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        // Avoid crashing the application due to unhandled exceptions.
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception on the OpenGL thread", t);
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW when using `SceneForm` you can call `getPlaneDiscoveryController().hide()`

Comment: That is for sceneform. I need it to be for arcore with plane renderer